# Incomplete list revisions of a file with Drive REST API v2

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Drive REST API v2 to list the revisions of a Google Doc or Sheet, but the resulting list is incomplete. I'm not able to retrieve the same list of files available at File > Revision History. I've detected the same behaviour with Drive REST API v3.

Is anyone having the same issue? May I have to send a specific param in order to get a detailed list?

Comment: I think you have the same issue with this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522334/accessing-google-docs-revision-history-through-the-api-using-r). It might help.

Comment: Thank you very much @noogui ! This is just what I was looking for :)