# In which cases the mimetypes of google docs changes?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, powerpoint, mime-types, google-slides-api

I have seen the file mimeType of one of google presentation on my team drive is changed from `application/vnd.google-apps.presentation` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`. I am not sure what's the reason? but can anyone tell me the possible reason?

Comment: How is this file being uploaded?

Comment: Its created in drive as an google-app presentation and moved to Team Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Google slides format

> application/vnd.google-apps.presentation

Microsoft power point format

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

If a power point file is uploaded to google drive without requesting that it be converted to a google slides format then it will be in the power point mime type.  If it is converted well then it will be in the google slides format.

Who or what ever uploaded that file forgot to [convert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types) it.

Comment: But Its changing the existing google-slides format to power point format. Keeping the file resource id same.

Comment: @SagarkumarUnhale check revisions of file and get author of revision and ask them what they did, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522334/accessing-google-docs-revision-history-through-the-api-using-r

Comment: User have created file in google-apps on drive and doesn't have changed its format. But user have just change the location of file, but does that impacted on changing of mimeType of file? 
I have tried to reproduce the issue by moving file to separate folder on my drive and also to shared drive, but in my case mimeType did not changed...

Comment: depends on what was used to change the location. if they used some application which did not set the mime type then it could be the cause of your issue. Ask the user how it was moved

Answer (score 0):

Some information I have gathered from the documentation which may help you.

```
<p>
    Google Apps Script Mime Type Enum
    In my code called: gasMimeType
</p>
    <a href="https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type"></a>
<pre>
    ----------------------------------------
    GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT
    GOOGLE_DRAWINGS
    GOOGLE_DOCS
    GOOGLE_FORMS
    GOOGLE_SHEETS
    GOOGLE_SITES
    GOOGLE_SLIDES
    FOLDER
    SHORTCUT
    BMP
    GIF
    JPEG
    PNG
    SVG
    PDF
    CSS
    CSV
    HTML
    JAVASCRIPT
    PLAIN_TEXT
    RTF
    ZIP

</pre>    
<p>    
    Google Workspace and Drive MIME Types 
    In my code called: driveMimeType
</p>
    <a href="https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types"></a>
<pre>
    ----------------------------------------
    application/vnd.google-apps.audio   
    application/vnd.google-apps.document
    application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk
    application/vnd.google-apps.drawing
    application/vnd.google-apps.file
    application/vnd.google-apps.folder
    application/vnd.google-apps.form
    application/vnd.google-apps.map
    application/vnd.google-apps.photo   
    application/vnd.google-apps.presentation
    application/vnd.google-apps.script
    application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut
    application/vnd.google-apps.site
    application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
    application/vnd.google-apps.unknown 
    application/vnd.google-apps.video

</pre>   
<p>    
    Non-Google Drive MIME Types 
    are called: driveMimeType in this code
</p>

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats
<pre>
    ----------------------------------------
Google Doc Format   Conversion Format        Corresponding MIME type
Documents           HTML                     text/html
                    HTML (zipped)            application/zip
                    Plain text               text/plain
                    Rich text                application/rtf
                    Open Office doc}         application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
                    PDF                      application/pdf
                    MS Word document         application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                    EPUB                     application/epub+zip
Spreadsheets        MS Excel                 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                    Open Office sheet        application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet
                    PDF                      application/pdf
                    CSV (first sheet only)   text/csv
                    (sheet only)             text/tab-separated-values
                    HTML (zipped)            application/zip
Drawings            JPEG                     image/jpeg
                    PNG                      image/png
                    SVG                      image/svg+xml
                    PDF                      application/pdf
Presentations       MS PowerPoint            application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                    Open Office presentation application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation
                    PDF                      application/pdf
                    Plain text               text/plain
Apps Scripts        JSON                     application/vnd.google-apps.script+json
</pre>
```